# Tracing interconnected Python executables on OS X

Tags: python, macos, frameworks

I have a rather long setup, then three questions at the end.
On OS X, the System Python framework contains three executables (let me give them short names):

```
> F=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6
> A=$F/bin/python2.6
> B=$F/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
> C=$F/Python
```

$A and $B are clearly too small to be Python itself.

```
> ls -s $A; ls -s $B; ls -s $C
16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
3152 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python

> $A
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
> $B
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
> $C
-bash: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python: cannot execute binary file
```

Despite equal size and apparently, effect, the first two are different, e.g.:

```
> cmp -lc $A $B
```

Also, in /usr/bin, python2.6 is a symlink to $C, but there is also:

```
> D=/usr/bin/python
> ls -s $D
48 /usr/bin/python
```

I want to sort out how these are connected;  the command `which` doesn't help.

```
> export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1
> $A
..
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
```

Summary:  $A loads $B followed by $C; $B loads $C; $D loads $B followed by $C

So my questions are:

1. Is this documented anywhere?
2. What roles do these play?
3. Most important, what tools would be useful in tracing connections like this?

Comment: How does it matter?  What problem are you having?  Without a context -- something you can't do -- this seems like the results don't help anybody do anything.

Comment: @S.Lott:  I'd like to understand how this setup works.  Even if you think that's not an appropriate question, #3 still is.  I left out nm, which helps show that $A and $B don't do much, but file doesn't really help at all.  I can live with answer #1, but I'm hoping for more specific tools.

Comment: more specific tools to do what? - Unix is a set of tools cooperating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple-supplied Pythons in OS X 10.6 are built and installed using the standard Python *framework* build option, with a few customization tweaks.  It is not in Apple's documentation because the specific layout is not an Apple invention; it has evolved over the years by the Python project using other OS X framework layouts as a starting point.  If you install a version of Python on OS X using one of the python.org installers, say from [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/), you will see the same pattern, with the framework rooted at `/Library/Frameworks/` rather than `/System/Library/Frameworks`.  So, if you are really curious, you can download the source and look at the `configure` script and `Makefile` templates.  It can be heavy reading, though.  Apple also makes available [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/) the source used to build open source components, including Python, in each OS X release along with the customization patches so, in theory, you can see exactly how Apple built what it released.

That said, to address your questions, in Python 2.6:

`$A` is the pythonw wrapper that ensures Python is recognized as a GUI application by OS X (see the source of `pythonw.c` [here](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release26-maint/Mac/Tools/pythonw.c?view=markup)).  Note, the Apple version of pythonw has been customized to add the preferred execution modes (see Apple's `man 1 python`).  A somewhat different approach to this is provided in the upstream source of newer versions of Python (2.7 and 3.2).

`$B` is the actual executable of the Python interpreter.  It is what is `exec`ed by the pythonw executable, `$A`.  You should be able to easily verify that by actually running Python and looking at the value of `sys.executable` but there is a bug with the Apple-supplied Python 2.6 (probably due to the added feature mentioned above) that causes the wrong value to be assigned to it.  The python.org Python 2.6.6 shows the correct value:

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6
$ ./bin/python2.6 -c 'import sys;print(sys.executable)'
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`
```

`$C` is the shared library containing all of the interpreter's loadable modules.  You can see that by using `otool` on `$B`:

```
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6
$ cd Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/
$ otool -L ./Python
Python:
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python (compatibility version 2.6.0, current version 2.6.1)
   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
```

Comment: For some reason, running $B on a Lion machine from the Python framework I built on a Mavericks machine, I get the system Python (different version)... Any idea what is going on? You said that was supposed to be the actual Python binary...

Comment: remram, without more information, one can only guess at your specific situation.  If you want to pursue it, please open a new question with all the pertinent details of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The tools to use are ls and file.

ls -l will give what the symbolic link goes to. The size of a symbolic link is the number of chafracters in the path it points to.

file x will give the type of the file

e.g.

```
file /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python (for architecture x86_64):      Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python (for architecture i386):        Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386  
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python (for architecture ppc7400):     Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
```

OSX Frameworks are described in [Apple developer docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000183i)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python and
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 are the actual python interpreter, I think they are hard links to the same binary.

/usr/bin/python is the python on the path - I think it is hard linked to /usr/bin/pythonw. These are wrappers that call exec to the real python interpreter in  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6 see [python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue6834)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current is a symlink to System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6 using the standard OSX Framework versioning

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python is the shared library that does all the work - set up as a library so that you can write programs in other languages that can embed a python interpreter.

For other details look at [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/using/mac.html) but I suspect you would have to search the [apple python mailing list](http://www.python.org/community/sigs/current/pythonmac-sig/)